# How to run custom config file in node.js project

Tags: javascript, node.js, config, local, environment

In a node.js project using express framework, usually config folder has 3 files:

- `config.json` - runs in prod env
- `development.json` - runs in dev env
- `staging.json` - runs in stage env

I want to create another config file called `example.json` and run local dev environment using `example.json` instead of `development.json` when ever the code is run with a special environment variable `process.env.LOCAL_PROD`.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [`node-config`](https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config) and I highly recommend it as it allows for multiple config files and even hostname based config files. It also supports multiple formats including `.js` configs not just `.json`, you can read more about the various setups for configuration files in the [`node-config` wiki](https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/wiki/Configuration-Files). I use it in almost all of my applications that require some configuration due to how easy it is to use.

Now if you don't want to use a package to handle this, then you can do it with just using `require()` since it can read and parse `.json` files as well as `.js`. The common environment variable to use when setting what environment the application is running within is named `NODE_ENV`.

```
let config
let env = process.env.NODE_ENV.toLowerCase()
if (env === 'production') {
  config = require('./config.json')
} else if (env === 'staging') {
  config = require('./staging.json')
} else if (env === 'dev') {
  config = require('./development.json')
} else {
  console.log('No configurable NODE_ENV detected, no config loaded')
}
```

Comment: There are other node modules which are using existing config based on env variable value. I am not using the file only at a single place.

Comment: Then pass the config around using dependency injection

Comment: what is dependency injection? can you elaborate?